# find and Replace a string in file python

Tags: python, python-2.7

command outpt:

```
   veera:~ # blkid
   /dev/sda1: UUID="41b8736f-5a43-4938-8b38-8df62fba50d7" TYPE="swap"
   /dev/sda2: UUID="3717cca6-cbb7-4763-a935-6e01dfa1f83c" TYPE="ext3"

  file output:
  veera:~ # cat /etc/fstab
  /dev/sda1            swap                 swap       defaults              0 0
  /dev/sda2            /                    ext3       acl,user_xattr        1 1
```

Could any one please help us how to replace /dev/sda1 to uuid in file /etc/fstab.

after file replacement it should look like below:

```
veera:~ # cat /etc/fstab
UUID=41b8736f-5a43-4938-8b38-8df62fba50d7            swap                 swap       defaults              0 0
UUID=3717cca6-cbb7-4763-a935-6e01dfa1f83c            /                    ext3       acl,user_xattr        1 1
```

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: `your_string.replace(old, new)`

Comment: what's your OS?

Comment: @ Roman Perekhrest linux

Answer (score 0):

I wrote code to replace the string as per question requirement.

Please validate and let me know is there better way to achieve this

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen('blkid', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
tmp = proc.stdout.read()

d = {}
for line in tmp.split("\n"):
        if ":" not in line:
                continue
        key,value = line.strip().split(":", 1)
        d[key] = value
with open('/etc/fstab', 'r') as file:
        filedata = file.read()
for k, v in d.iteritems():
        for line in filedata.split("\n"):
                if k in line:
                        data = v.strip().split(" ")
                        data = data[0].replace("\"","")
                        filedata = filedata.replace(k, data)
with open('/etc/fstab', 'w') as file:
        file.write(filedata)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are on Linux OS, here is *one-liner* using **awk** tool:

```
awk -F' |: ' 'NR==FNR{ a[$1]=$2; next } $1 in a { $1=a[$1]; print }' <(blkid) /etc/fstab
```

The output:

```
UUID="41b8736f-5a43-4938-8b38-8df62fba50d7"            swap                 swap       defaults              0 0
UUID="3717cca6-cbb7-4763-a935-6e01dfa1f83c"            /                    ext3       acl,user_xattr        1 1
```